# File to server and name to database

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

Hello guys got a problem here, im uploading an image to server, and i want to keep the name on my db, this is my code, the problem is that the file is uploadin corectly but my sql sentence wont save the information.

```
require('cone.php');
//*--------------------------------Se guarda la imagen----------------------------*

    $file = $_FILES["file"];
$nombre = getUniqueName()."";
$tipo = $file["type"];
$ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"];
$size = $file["size"];
$carpeta = "upload/";

switch ($tipo) {
    case 'image/jpg':
        $tipo = JPG;
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $tipo = JPEG;
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $tipo = PNG;
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $tipo = GIF;
        break;
    default:
        die("Error, el archivo no es una imagen"); 
}  


$src = $carpeta.$nombre;
move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);
changeSize($src, 500, $tipo);
echo "<img src='$src'>";

 $con = Conectar();
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO bolsa (id, tipo_bolsa, titulo, imagen, descripcion, categoria, fecha, sueldo) VALUES (:id, :tipo_bolsa, :titulo, :imagen, :descripcion, :categoria, :fecha, :sueldo)';
    $q = $con->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':tipo_bolsa'=>$tipo_bolsa, ':titulo'=>$titulo, ':imagen'=>$carpeta.$nombre, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion, ':categoria'=>$categoria, ':fecha'=>$fecha, ':sueldo'=>$sueldo));
```

The sql sentences does not execute...

Comment: you said "This part is not executed, without the file code it works just fine" // post the code which "works just fine", please..

Comment: I edit my post bro, can you check it please...

Comment: In this case we need to see more. "changeSize" may alter the name of a file. I suggest you to comment out a "changeSize" row, and see what it does.

Comment: I did it, but the final result is the same, the sql sentence does not execute :/

Comment: `$tipo_bolsa` is never defined. Probably you meant `$tipo`.
For more help, please post the error message of the database server.

Comment: Furthermore, you should not use $file['type'] to check the image type. An attacker could fake that value and execute PHP code on your server!

Comment: Yes sorry tipo_bolsa and other values didn't matter, thats info of a form, but it dont affect anithing